# Updating Sql Server Row with increasing ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I update sql server with increasing ID according to another column?

I have a table with following structure:

```
sn  name    val
    test     0
    test     0.5
    test     2
    test1    0
    test1    0.5
    test1     2
```

How do i update it so that is will be:

```
sn  name      val
1    test      0
2    test      0.5
3    test      2
1    test1     0
2    test1     0.5
3    test1     2
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c28e7)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using [`Row_Number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and the [`OVER ... PARTITION BY` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), if you have a key column in the table. I added a column: `Id int identity primary key` and here's the update:

```
;with RowNumberedData as (
  select 
    id, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by name
      order by id
    ) as rowno
  from sql_test
)
update s
  set sn = r.rowno
from sql_test s
join RowNumberedData r
  on s.id = r.id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43fa8/4

Answer (score 2):

Use cte and row_number

Here is an example :

```
create table #mytable (sn int, name varchar(20), val money)

insert into #mytable values (null, 'test', 0.5)
insert into #mytable values (null, 'test', 1)
insert into #mytable values (null, 'test1', 0.5)
insert into #mytable values (null, 'test1', 1)

;with cte as (select row_number() over (order by name, val) as rn, * from #mytable)
update cte set sn = rn

select * from #mytable
```

Comment: I think you missed partion by

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Also as soon as you have to start new counter for each NAME value you should use `PARTITON by NAME` in this statement.

```
WITH T AS 
(select sql_test.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Val) as RowNumber
        from sql_test)
UPDATE T SET SN=RowNumber;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dff3/1)